# Taking runable class and making it into it's own thread

Tags: java, multithreading, handler, runnable

Hey all new to Java some I'm sure this is something simple but just can not get it correctly in order for it to work.

The original java code for this runnable class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ChatServer {
    private static Set < String > names = new HashSet < > ();
    private static Set < PrintWriter > writers = new HashSet < > ();
    public static int thePort = 8877;

    private static boolean isPortInUse(String host, int port) throws SocketException {
        boolean result = false;

        try {
            (new Socket(host, port)).close();
            result = true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Could not connect.
        }

        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running...");
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
        boolean hasPort = isPortInUse("localhost", thePort);

        try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(thePort)) {
            while (true) {
                pool.execute(new Handler(listener.accept()));
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Handler implements Runnable {
        private String name;
        private Socket socket;
        private Scanner in ;
        private PrintWriter out;

        public Handler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                while (true) {
                    out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                    name = in .nextLine();

                    if (name == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    synchronized(names) {
                        if (!name.isEmpty() && !names.contains(name)) {
                            names.add(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                out.println("NAMEACCEPTED " + name);

                for (PrintWriter writer: writers) {
                    writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + " has joined");
                }

                writers.add(out);

                while (true) {
                    String input = in .nextLine();

                    if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("/quit")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    for (PrintWriter writer: writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    writers.remove(out);
                }

                if (name != null) {
                    System.out.println(name + " has left");
                    names.remove(name);

                    for (PrintWriter writer: writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + " has left");
                    }
                }
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thread code that I created is this:

```
static Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    private String name;
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner in ;
    private PrintWriter out;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Set < String > names = new HashSet < > ();
            Set < PrintWriter > writers = new HashSet < > ();
            int thePort = 8877;

            System.out.println("The chat server is running...");
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
            boolean hasPort = isPortInUse("localhost", thePort);

            try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(thePort)) {
                while (true) {
                    pool.execute(new Handler(listener.accept()));
                }
            }
            try {
                in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                while (true) {
                    out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                    name = in .nextLine();

                    if (name == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    synchronized(names) {
                        if (!name.isEmpty() && !names.contains(name)) {
                            names.add(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                out.println("NAMEACCEPTED " + name);

                for (PrintWriter writer: writers) {
                    writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + " has joined");
                }

                writers.add(out);

                while (true) {
                    String input = in .nextLine();

                    if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("/quit")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    for (PrintWriter writer: writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    writers.remove(out);
                }

                if (name != null) {
                    System.out.println(name + " has left");
                    names.remove(name);

                    for (PrintWriter writer: writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + " has left");
                    }
                }

                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void Handler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    private boolean isPortInUse(String host, int port) throws SocketException {
        boolean result = false;

        try {
            (new Socket(host, port)).close();
            result = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Could not connect.
        }

        return result;
    }    
});
```

The only 2 errors I have out of all of that code above is:

> Handler cannot be resolved to a type

on

```
pool.execute(new Handler(listener.accept()));
```

and

> Return type for the method is missing

on

```
public Handler(Socket socket) {
```

So what do I need to change in order to replace Handler so that it will work with the thread code I created?

**UPDATE #1**

my main class where i call both server and client:

```
        @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
        private static void placeChatOnScreen() {
            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            textField.setDragEnabled(true);
            textField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
            textField.setBounds(338, 838, 954, 22);
            frame.getContentPane().add(textField);

            messageArea = new JTextArea();
            messageArea.setEditable(false);
            messageArea.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            messageArea.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
            messageArea.setDragEnabled(true);
            messageArea.setName("chatArea");
            messageArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            messageArea.setBounds(338, 648, 954, 181);
            frame.getContentPane().add(messageArea);

            textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    out.println(textField.getText());
                    textField.setText("");
                }
            });

             // start server
            final Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Handler());
            serverThread.start();
            // wait a bit
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // start client
            clientThread.start();
        }
```

> And this is the server class (as you said to put it in):

```
public class ChatServer {
    private static Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
    private static Set<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<>();
    public static int thePort = 8877;

    private static boolean isPortInUse(String host, int port) throws SocketException {
      boolean result = false;

      try {
        (new Socket(host, port)).close();
        result = true;

      }
      catch(IOException e) {
        // Could not connect.
      }

      return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running...");
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
        boolean hasPort = isPortInUse("localhost", thePort);

        try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(thePort)) {
            while (true) {
                pool.execute(new Handler(listener.accept()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Handler implements Runnable {
        private String name;
        private Socket socket;
        private Scanner in;
        private PrintWriter out;

        public Handler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                while (true) {
                    out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                    name = in.nextLine();

                    if (name == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    synchronized (names) {
                        if (!name.isEmpty() && !names.contains(name)) {
                            names.add(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                out.println("NAMEACCEPTED " + name);

                for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                    writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + " has joined");
                }

                writers.add(out);

                while (true) {
                    String input = in.nextLine();

                    if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("/quit")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    writers.remove(out);
                }

                if (name != null) {
                    System.out.println(name + " has left");
                    names.remove(name);

                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + " has left");
                    }
                }
                try { socket.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**update #2**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You declared a `private` class, which won't be accessible from other classes

```
private static class Handler implements Runnable { ... }
```

So, simply mark it as `public` or package-private (no modifier), if they share the same package

```
public static class Handler implements Runnable { ... }
```

Then, do

```
final Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Handler());
serverThread.start();
```

Comment: But i don't have a **private static class Handler implements Runnable { ... }** in my new thread code??

Comment: @StealthRT misunderstood, sorry. You can reuse your  older Handler class. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry @lppEdd - i still dont understand. In my thread code (the second chunk of code in my OP) i do not have a **private static class Handler implements Runnable { ... }**. That is in the **original class** that i am transferring over to a thread.

Comment: @StealthRT Why are you copying everything inside a Thread? Maintain the Helper as a separate class.

Comment: Hum... seems that i get the same error just on the **final Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Handler());** now instead of the other place it was.

Comment: @StealthRT your Handler class accepts a Socket argument in the constructor. You need to pass that when doing "new Handler(...)"

Comment: @StealthRT here  "new Thread(new Handler());" you need to pass a Socket to Handler constructor. Example "new Thread(new Handler(socket));"

Comment: i placed what i think you are saying in another update in the OP.

Comment: @StealthRT thanks, can you post the entire class of the "placeChatOnScreen" method?

Comment: @StealthRT move your classes to a named package. Don't use the default one (which is no package basically).

Comment: @StealthRT yes, but that's the **default package**, move them to a **named** / **custom** one.

Comment: @StealthRT when you moved them, update the import reference to "import yourpackage.ChatServer.Handler;". Where "yourpackage" is the name of the package you created.

Comment: Ok i moved them but i dont see anywhere its telling me to **import uftPak.ChatServer.Handler.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190996/discussion-between-lppedd-and-stealthrt).